# How use Logstash in Magento2 in Docker?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, logging, docker, monolog

I want to have Docker container with Magento2 shop and container with Logstash. Also I have independent Elasticsearch server. I want to send all logs from Magento with build-in Monolog logger to Logstash and then to Elasticsearch sever. 
Can anybody help me? thanks.

Comment: I have problem with finding wright way for sending all logging information (core and custom) from Magento2 shop (in separate Docker container) to Logstash port (in another Docker container) with out saving in log files. Thats mean any logging event must send info to Logstash port. Configuration of Docker is not big problem for me. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the following link this might help you.

[Setting up Magento 2 on docker](https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento2)

https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento2

[Using docker for magento2 development](https://magento.evozon.com/using-docker-for-magento-2-development.html)